# Custom SoundCloud scrubber bar does not function events in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, soundcloud

I made a scrubber/seek bar for a SoundCloud track. Clicking on anywhere on the the seek bar must seek the track to that part. That's what the click event I made is meant to do. It does work on Chrome, but doesn't work on Safari. 
Here is a working example on Chrome which does not work on Safari. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsuoe56c/5/)

This is  my JS code related to click event:

```
function updatePosition(){
  var currentPosition = scTrack.getCurrentPosition();
  var duration = scTrack.getDuration();

$(".scrubberPlaying").css('width', ((currentPosition / duration) * 100) + '%');    
    $(".scrubberBase").on("click", function (e) {
                x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
                width = $(this).width(),
                scTrack.seek((x / width) * duration);
    });
}
```

I think the `seek` method from SoundCloud does not work correctly. However, does anyone know why isnt it working on Safari ?